# how do i let this run without affecting others?

Tags: c#, discord.net

So, i was making a discord bot that would be able to change a role's colour every after a certain amount of time. it ran properly, however, the bot is unable to register other commands or run any other work while this task is being run. (it wont stop when the stop command is run as it couldn't get in there in the first place).

i was hoping someone here could help fix this problem.

so here's part of the code:

```
[Group("rainbow")]
public class Rainbow : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
{
    public Boolean enabled;

    [Command, RequireUserPermission(GuildPermission.ManageRoles)]
    public async Task rainbowAsync(SocketRole role, int milliseconds)
    {
        if (milliseconds >= 500) {
                 enabled = true;       
            while (enabled)
            {
                Random rnd = new Random();
                double id = rnd.NextDouble() * 7;

                if (id < 1)
                {
                    await role.ModifyAsync(a => a.Color = Discord.Color.Red);
                }
                else if (id < 2)
                {
                    await role.ModifyAsync(a => a.Color = Discord.Color.Orange);
                }
                else if (id < 3)
                {
                    await role.ModifyAsync(a => a.Color = Discord.Color.LightOrange);
                }
                else if (id < 4)
                {
                    await role.ModifyAsync(a => a.Color = Discord.Color.Green);
                }
                else if (id < 5)
                {
                    await role.ModifyAsync(a => a.Color = Discord.Color.Blue);
                }
                else if (id < 6)
                {
                    await role.ModifyAsync(a => a.Color = Discord.Color.DarkBlue);
                }
                else if (id < 7)
                {
                    await role.ModifyAsync(a => a.Color = Discord.Color.Purple);
                }

                await Task.Delay(milliseconds);
            }
        }
        else { await ReplyAsync("Time value must be higher than 500ms"); }

    }

    [Command("stop"), RequireUserPermission(GuildPermission.ManageRoles)]
    public async Task StopAsync()
    {
        enabled = false;
        await ReplyAsync("Rainbow effect stopped");
    }
}
```

Comment: You really need to provide a [mcve].  Take a look at [ask].

Comment: "it wont stop when the stop command is run as it couldn't get in there in the first place"
We kind of need to know what is going on that is preventing it from getting there... like, what does the code look like that is failing to reach the StopAsync().

Comment: The rest of the code should be fine as other commands with similiar structures run fine

Comment: It can't do anything else because your Task is stuck in an infinite while loop. The Task needs to be completed or halted before it can handle another Task. I think your StopAsync() is queued but it cannot be executed because of this. You could probably fix this by using a method that checks if "stop" was in the message context and set the enabled boolean to false in your main class.

Answer (score -1):

As Alex mentioned in his comment,

Your command goes into an infinite loop.

```
if (milliseconds >= 500) {
    enabled = true;       
    while (enabled)
    {
        //Code
        await Task.Delay(milliseconds);
    }
}
```

This puts your command into an infinite loop which prevents other commands from firing. The reason this prevents other commands from firing in an Async environment is because Async is still just a single thread and the default way Discord.net calls your command is `await Command();`

When an async call is awaited it blocks the call until the Task completes. Your task will never complete because of the infinite loop.

There are a couple different ways to handle this, but the way I would suggest to handle it is to schedule the recoloring. Look into ways to schedule tasks to happen every x time-frame.

As an example

```
public class TimerTask
{
    private readonly Timer _taskTimer;

    public TimerTask(Action action, int interval = 10000)
    {
        _taskTimer = new Timer { AutoReset = true, Interval = interval };
        _taskTimer.Elapsed += (_, __) => action();
    }
    public void Start() { _taskTimer.Start(); }

    public void Stop() { _taskTimer.Stop(); }
}
```

Comment: Just because asynchronous code doesn't require multiple threads to run doesn't mean that asynchronous code blocks the code that starts the operation for the duration.  In fact, if it did, then *by definition* it would be a synchronous method.  The *definition* of an asynchronous method is that it returns to the caller immediately instead of waiting for the actual operation to finish.

Comment: Unless the default RunMode for his commands are set to RunMode.Async then the commands themselves are called awaited. Awaiting a call to a method with an infinite loop will indeed block. Setting the default run mode to RunMode.Async can cause bigger issues like reentry problems and race conditions. I would recommend and did recommend to just write a timed scheduler to handle fire over time events instead of adding the possibility of other issues just to run a infinite loop in a command. I worded my answer a little wrong albiet. I'll change it abit.

Comment: Again, `await` *does not block the current thread*.  It is asynchronous.  It is not blocking any thread, it is merely scheduling some work to run at a later time *while no thread is waiting on it*.

Comment: It is blocking the current context. Try it yourself... start up an async main (you can with C# 7.2 or higher) and call an awaited task with an infinite loop. No code past that await will ever fire.
Same thing is happening with his code. The command gets called awaited and it blocks the context. No other command (Being its blocked waiting for the context) will fire.

Comment: I just thought of a slightly better way to put this with the way discord.net works. Unless its RunMode.Async the commands are called awaited on the main thread. Await will block the thread they are called on while waiting for that work that was scheduled till later finally finishes and returns its promised return. Being discord.net calls all the commands on the main thread....  awaiting them will block every other command until the last command ends... which in the askers case will never come to realization. If he sets RunMode.async then they are called without await and will not block anyting

Comment: But no point on me going on about this.... I understand how async/await works, but apparently can't explain it in a way that will get you to understand what I am saying because in your thoughts async/await can never block anything.

Comment: Sure, it's entirely possible that the caller of the method is scheduling work to happen after the asynchronous operation finishes, and you might not wait it holding off on that work for the duration of the asynchronous operation, but *that's not blocking a thread*.

Comment: I think you're talking about two different things. What Servy said is true, a thread is not blocked with `await`, however what JParks means is that the Discord library will wait for that awaited task to complete, because the library itself is asynchronous.